# TYPO3 add property and method to the model

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18, I need add some property to model user

```
$public age = 0;
```

and I tried add different methods :

```
public setAge(){$this->age = 23;}
public age(){return $this->age;}
public getAge(){return $this->age;}
public age(){return 23;}
public getAge(){return 23;}
```

And on fluid I always get 0. {user.age} - I get 0. What is the problem ? May be because I have not field 'age' in DB table ? But I need add age property to user model without field in DB. Is it possible ? how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

- What user model are you talking about?
- fe_user, beuser - or something completly different?
- How did you tried to add these?
- Have you created a custom class which extends the user class?

Greetings,
KamiYang

Answer (score 0):

you must define your getter in this way:

```
public function getAge()
{
  return 23;
}
```

In your examples you have forgot the `function` declaration.

If this don't work, check if the correct domain model is gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like below.

```
/**
 * @var Age
 */
protected $age = 23;

public function __construct($age) {
   $this->setAge($age);
}

public function setAge($age) {
   $this->age = $age;
}

public function getAge() {
   return $this->age;
}
```